# How to change the orientation of a DataGrid's column header in C#?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridcolumnheader

I defined a `DataGrid` in my WPF and I want to make some column headers appear in vertical form. In [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257724), this is done via MVVM. But how can I do this in C# code?

In other words, the method that used MVVM changes the orientation of *all* column headers. But I want some of headers to be vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda asked this question again in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39314550) (in another form though). The accepted answer solved my problem. I advise the future readers with the same issues to refer to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39314550). In summary, you have to define multiple styles for the `DataGridColumnHeader` and also assign an event handler to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event. And then, apply the desired style programmatically.

It seems abiding to the MVVM pattern is an overkill.